# In R how to exclude certain rows when calculating quantile()

Tags: r, subset

I'm interested in calculating the `quantile` function of a column in a data frame for only a subset of rows based upon another column.

For example, I have a `new_user_indicator` column with "Y" or "N", and want to know the quantile for "Y" group. Currently I am doing

```
quantile(subset_df$limit_amount, .25)
subset_df <- subset(carddata, new_user_indicator == "Y")
```

Is there a way to do this in one command rather than creating a subsetted data frame?

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891409/how-to-exclude-certain-observations-while-generating-summary-statistics-without) to see if it could help but wasn't able to decipher part of the code.

Thanks

Comment: How about `quantile(subset(carddata, new_user_indicator == "Y")$limit_amount, .25)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantile function itself does not allow you operate on a subset. So you do need some way to extract subset data.

However, it is not recommended to extract a subset data frame, as you did. `quantile` accepts a vector, so you only need to subset a column rather than the whole data frame.

```
quantile(with(carddata, limit_amount[new_user_indicator == "Y"]), 0.25)
```

The `with` function helps extract column, otherwise you need

```
quantile(carddatal$imit_amount[carddata$new_user_indicator == "Y"], 0.25)
```

---

**update**

If you are to do this repeatedly, then write a function (change function name `foo` to your favourite)

```
foo <- function(df, out_var, in_var, in_level, prob) {
  quantile(df[[out_var]][df[[in_var]] == in_level], prob)
  }
```

Then you can do:

```
foo(carddata, "limit_amount", "new_user_indicator", "Y", 0.25)
```

I am assuming you have another level "N", so for that level you can do

```
foo(carddata, "limit_amount", "new_user_indicator", "N", 0.25)
```

Here, `out_var`, `in_var` are column names (hence a string) for output variable an input variable. `in_level` is the level for input variable. And you know what `prob` is for.

---

**a more powerful way**

If you want a 0.25 for **all** levels of input variable, then using my function is yet stupid. Use `tapply`

```
tapply(carddata$limit_amount, cardata$new_user_indicator, FUN = quantile, prob = 0.25)
```

`tapply(x1, x2, FUN, ...)` will apply `quantile(x1, ...)` to according to `x2`. If you have 10 levels in `x2`, then you get 0.25 quantile for all of them.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the detail you provided. I'm going to test then approve but I appreciate the info you provided.